# react-google-charts package is not importing

Tags: reactjs, npm, react-google-charts

The react-google-charts package is not imported correctly inside the react package component.

```
import { Chart } from 'react-google-charts';
console.log('Chart', Chart);
```

The log is printing a null value.

The overview of what I have done:

- I have created a reactjs application which has 2 packages
- I require implementing 3d pie chart
- I installed react-google-charts into one of the packages and also to the overall app.
- When I import the charts at the app level it's working
- When I import the charts in the package level it returns null

Thanks in advance for any solution.